# Implementing Equals method in Java

Tags: java, equals, comparator

I am writing a Comparator which is going to compare Old & New Object using equals method. This is the Hierarchy of by Objects.

```
   User
      -> Address
                -> HomeAddress
                -> OfficeAddress
      -> BussinessInformation
                -> String:NatureOfBussiness
                   ...
                   ...
      -> Product
      -> List<Service> services
```

and so on...

As soon as equals method got called on User Object I need to return a StringBuilder with # separated fields that will give me information with the list of  the fields got changed.

eg: natureofbussness#officeaddress

as my equals method in java returns true/false I want this to return fields that are changed now.

So that code now looks like..

```
 StringBuilder fieldsChanged=UserComparator.compare(oldUser,newUser);

 // fieldsChanged = "homeAddress#officeAddress#product";
```

Can someone help me how to achieve this? As, I have to call this equals on subsequent object recursively and get the output in a single stringbuilder object

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: you need to implement equals in a nested manner in every class.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The `equals` method should check whether two objects are equal. **And not more**. It should **not** change any *state* (because you hardly know when the method will be called). From the description, you should probably **not** do this in the `equals` method, but instead introduce a method that allows you to do something like `StringBuilder sb = computeChangedFields(firstObject, secondObject);`.

Comment: I would suggest reading the chapter in Effective Java 2nd Edition Items 8 and 9.  Further, once you've understood what a proper equals method should look like and maybe have written a couple by hand in practice (not production code), offload this to the auto generation capabilities of your IDE (IntelliJ IDEA's equals/hashcode generation is quite good).  Overriding equals/hashcode is important enough to do correctly each time, but mundane enough that you shouldn't spend much time on it if possible.